# What is the best Optimised DynamoDB Query?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Let's say there is a dynamodb with as columns as below

| EmployeeId | employeeDetails | academicDetails | joiningDate | employeRemarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | xyz | pqr | 123456[timestamp] | Avg |

Employee performance fields take the following set of values `Average, Excellent, Outstanding, BelowAverage, Unworthy`. I want to retrieve all employees whose employee remarks are Average or Excellent or BelowAverage & their joining dates must be between 123000 timestamp t1 to 123999 timestamp t2.

Is creating GSI with partition key as `employeeRemarks` & sort key as `joiningDate` a better solution? What other solutions I can explore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use-case it's probably the best solution. But be aware of the partition limits in DynamoDB, you are creating an index on a low cardinality key, meaning each key can only provide a max throughput of 1000 WCU. If you feel like you need more than 1000 WCU for any of those keys, you would need to write shard.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html